# No page transition when dev tools of Chrome opening

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I tried to run JS script to open a new window, but it doesn't work unless I close the dev tools by pressing F12.

Comment: Can we see your code? If you're using `window.open`, this is often blocked as a popup unless a user action has triggered it (usually a click). What have you tried? What specifically didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

What F12 panel toggle does (for *the page*, the javascript) is a resize event - the height of the inner page changed. So you likely have something happening on resize event that makes it work. Open the page and resize it slightly and you will probably see the same result as closing the devtools. Check your code for a "resize" event and see if logic is added there.